# MongoDB Data disappeared

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I just had to do an emergency reboot of my linux server. I did it gracefully, not a hard reboot. I have been gathering data through a node.js app for a month, but when the server started up again, all the data was gone!

I have a long log file: http://clintberry.com/mongod.log

I also ran a repair to see if it would help but to no avail.

**New Development**
It looks like I was running mongo with the command 'service mongod start' and when I try to run that command again, I get this:

```
************** 
old lock file: /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock.  probably means unclean shutdown recommend
removing file and running --repair see: http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair 
for more information
*************
```

So that means the repair I was trying was not working since I wasn't using the correct config file.

When I run repair with the correct config file it doesn't seem to run repair, just spits out this:

```
root@es2 [/var/log/mongo]# mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/ --repair
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=26916 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo/ 64-bit
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 [initandlisten] db version v1.8.4, pdfile version 4.5
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 [initandlisten] git version: 81f12749a15e3d158b1b16bab6bc3faea538e166
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 [initandlisten] build sys info: Linux bs-linux64.10gen.cc 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
**************
old lock file: /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock.  probably means unclean shutdown
recommend removing file and running --repair
see: http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for more information
*************
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: old lock file, terminating
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 dbexit:
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 closeAllFiles() finished
Wed Nov 30 12:09:40 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: Are you sure that the data was there in there first place, and there wasn't an issue with saving it to the db?

Comment: It was there, because I ran map reduce on it nightly and it showed up in the report.

Comment: Clint, is the dbpath you specified when restarting it the same? From your log, it looks like you were using /var/lib/mongo - what are the contents of that directory?

Comment: @mpobrien - That must be the issue. When running with the service command it uses a default configuration file which sets the dbpath. But it must not be the default path.

Comment: Okay, so I added the new info. Running repair with the correct dbpath is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently you have to remove the lock file first, then run repair. Thanks for your suggestion mpobrien. I would have checked your answer if you added one.

Comment: In 2.0 mongodb doesn't require removing of the lock file anymore, thus the docs advise not to remove the mongodb.lock under any circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *mpobrien*'s comment suggested, the issue was that when starting mongo it was using a different dbpath (location for the data). For those that have mongo installed on CentOS, if you use the service command to start mongo,

```
service mongod start
```

then mongo will use the configuration file /etc/mongo.conf when starting, which puts your dbpath as /var/lib/mongo

but if you start mongo with the regular mongod command, it will not use that folder and will use the mongo default.

Thanks for the help.